# How to dynamically modify multiple dataframes in a loop?

Tags: r

I am creating multiple data frames inside a loop using `assign`, but once they have been created, how do I modify them inside the same loop?

For example the following code...

```
for(i in 1:3) {
assign(paste0("df", i),data.frame(A=c('a','b','c'),B=c("","","")))
}
```

create three dataframe, namely df1,df2, and df3 each looking like this...

```
  A B
1 a  
2 b  
3 c
```

With the B column blank.

Desired output is to have the value of 'i' inside the B column while creating df[i]. So df2 would be...

```
  A B
1 a 2
2 b 2
3 c 2
```

**Important:** Note that while I could do that inside the `assign` command itself in this case, in the larger problem that I am working on, I need to do the assignment outside the `assign` command as the dataframe I am creating is actually a subset of a larger dataframe not a new dataframe itself.

I have tried...

```
for(i in 1:3) {
assign(paste0("df", i),data.frame(A=c('a','b','c'),B=c("","","")))
paste0("df", i)$B <- i
}
```

... which doesn't work. What can work in place of `paste0("df", i)$B <- i`?

Comment: why clutter your global environment? Why not have all your dataframes in a list? And if the dataframe is a subset of the larger dataframe, why not use any of the packages often used for grouped operations?

Comment: @Heroka, would having the dataframe in a list make this dynamic modification easier?

Comment: @Heroka, I have to use dynamic subsetting, where even the number of subsets vary based on input. This is the easiet way I could figure out.

Comment: can you elaborate a bit on the larger problem you're trying to solve? How are subsets determined/made? Do they overlap?

Comment: @Heroka... I have a larger dataframe to be split into multiple subsets based where my input is the 'number of subsets' and '% of observations'. So I can have a single subset containing 100% values of larger set of 3 subsets containing 50%, 30% and 20% values respectively. And I have to give labels to each subset which specify the percentage.

Comment: @Heroka, the larger problem is too larger to make a reproducible example of sadly... But I have solved it largely.... the only step I am stuck at is the one mentioned in the question

Comment: I might (will also give you the list answer). Are the subsets random, or based on order (first 50%, second 30%, final 20%?)?

Comment: They are random (as in the splitting is random), but mutually exclusive of each other, and always add up to 100%.

Comment: @Heroka This solves the problem in its current format. But sadly my larger problem is not just based on percentage but also two more variables. But I'll accept your answer in a while... just let me try using your approach of lists to address my larger problem... In reality I have worked out a solution to subsetting but just stuck at the `paste0("df", i)$B <- i`... but I suppose there is no way around it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I always try to keep things I will doing the same things to inside something. that can be a dataframe or a list, but it won't clutter my global environment and object manipulation is easier.

```
###create some data

set.seed(123)
nobs=100
dat <- data.frame(id=1:nobs,x=rnorm(nobs),y=runif(nobs))

n_subsets = 3
percentages = c(50,30,20)

#create sample_flags: list of 'labels', with
#each label being x percent of total

subset_labels <- sprintf("%.f%%",percentages)
subset_flags <- sample(rep(subset_labels , times=percentages*nrow(dat)/100))

#or, depending on larger problem
#subset_flags <- sample(subset_labels, size=nrow(dat), prob=percentages/100, replace=T)

#(might not work nicely with all numbers of obs, but I'm guessing you've solved that)

#random part
dat$mysubset <- subset_flags

#do stuff for each subset, like mean of y orcount
library(data.table)

setDT(dat)[,.(.N, meany=mean(y)),mysubset]

> setDT(dat)[,.(.N, meany=mean(y)),mysubset]
   mysubset  N     meany
1:      30% 30 0.5632690
2:      50% 50 0.4717880
3:      20% 20 0.405884
```

or if you really want a list

```
mylist  <- lapply(1:3,function(x){
  data.frame(A=c('a','b','c'),B=c("","",""))
}
)
mylist <- lapply(1:3, function(i){
  r <- mylist[[i]]
  r$i <- i
  r
})
```

Answer (score 2):

As comments say, this is a good opportunity to use a list (based on the limited information given).

I would:

```
l = lapply(1:3, function(i){
   data.frame(A=c("a", "b", "c"), B=i)
})
```

If you desperately want to assign column B separately:

```
l = lapply(1:3, function(i){
   x = data.frame(A=c("a", "b", "c"))
   x$B = i
   x
})
```

As a side note, I'm not sure what benefit you get from `assign` so I've not included it in my example.